# How to display the user summary list of openfire in java console

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

I am very new to Openfire and XMPP, I want to display that usersummary list of Openfire in my console so the user can see who is online and then chat with online user .

Answer (score 0):

XMPP client is available with good documentation. I think following links will help you with your requirement.

Documentation: 
http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/gettingstarted.html

Download Client from here:
http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/download-landing.jsp?file=smack/smack_4_0_7.zip